# Graph planarity testing via adjacency matrix

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, planar-graphs, polynomial-time

I have looked at several efficient graph planarity algorithms which 
rely on computing and traversing DFS trees
(that add one vertex/edge/path at a time).

I am looking for graph planarity algorithms based on 
the adjacency matrix and operations on it, e.g. 
taking the square of the matrix, 
computing the eigenvalues of the matrix, etc.

Comment: I don't see why it is important to use whole matrix but the running time is not important. Anyways, if you are looking for an easy to explain algorithm, a planar graph does not have K_{3,3} and K_5 as a minor and one can test this in polynomial time.

Comment: It would beneficial if you add a motivation section to your post and explain why you are interested in this.

Answer (score 5):

Ignoring trivial responses like, recreate the graph from the matrix and apply any standard planarity algorithm, the closest I know of to a matrix-based planarity test is [Whitney's planarity criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney%27s_planarity_criterion). But it uses the incidence matrix, not the adjacency matrix, and is a mathematical criterion rather than a polynomial time algorithm.

It states that a graph is planar if and only if its matroid (the independence matroid of the columns of the signed incidence matrix) has a dual (the matroid for the dual space of the column space) which is also a graphic matroid.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, but i need some more explanatation - how can it become an algoritm? - can i find a graphic matroid dual in poyinomial time? furt

Comment: further more - I see from wikipedia that a graphic matroid must have more forbidden minor to check ( uiform matroid and Fano plane in addtion to M(K_3,3),M(K_5)) doesn't it make the check for planirity much more complex?

Comment: You didn't ask for a non-complex-to-implement criterion, you asked for a matrix-based one.